# What does shopt histreedit do?

Tags: command-history, shopt

`shopt histreedit` is supposed to allow the user to re-edit a failed history substitution.

How can a history substitution fail?

How is `histreedit` different from `histverify`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can a history substitution fail?

Let's say you want to re-run the last `ls` command, but you mistype the history substitution as `!lss`. Assuming you don't have a command starting with `lss`,

- With standard options,

  ```
  $ !lss
  bash: !lss: event not found
  $
  ```
- With `shopt -s histreedit`, the prompt gets reset so it's easier to fix it.

  ```
  $ !lss
  bash: !lss: event not found
  $ !lss
  ```

> How is `histreedit` different from `histverify`?

`histverify` won't try to execute any command containing a history substitution; instead, it will set the prompt to the would-be resulting command.

```
$ ls -a
.dotfile file1  file2  file3  ...
$ !ls
.dotfile file1  file2  file3  ...
$ shopt -s histverify
$ !ls
$ ls -a
```

This is essentially a confirmation step, and might come in handy. E.g., if you try `echo "hi!!"`, Bash substitutes `!!` by the last issued command (double-quotes do not disable history expansion) and silently executes the result. Obviously this could do harm with other commands. With `histverify`, you can abort and fix it in case the history expansion was unintended.